# How to do an email duplication check in the Put (update) method when another user already has the same email registered?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, sequelize.js

In the backend of the node application, I want to do an email check when another user already has the same email registered. It already works well when I use the POST method, but when doing an update with PUT, the current routine identifies the user's own email to be changed as a duplicate (because he is already registered in the database), I didn't want that and it doesn't even make sense, I would like that in the update, it would not be considered the email of the user that I am changing, but to check if there is any other user with equivalent email.

I tried the following code:

```
chekEmailDuplicate = (req, res) => {
   User.findOne({//Tenta localizar algum usuário
            where: {//onde
                   id: !req.body.id,
                email: req.body.email
            }
        }).then(user => {
            if (user) {
                res.status(400).send("Fail -> Email is already in use!");
                return;
            }
}
```

As we can see in the code above, in:

```
id: !req.body.id
```

I tried something like consider the id different from the user being modified, but it does NOT work, the application accepts duplicate email just the same! No POST is a wonder, but with the PUT will not.

Could someone who's in Node or already knows how to solve help me?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: if you want to check against email then remove the id: !req.body.id condition. Also ! is the operator for Node not for mongo, for mongo you will have to use $ne operator.

Comment: Don't use put for updating but rather only for creating

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [$ne](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/ne/)

```
User.findOne({
  where: {
    id: {$ne: req.body.id}
    email: req.body.email
  }
}).then(user => {
  if (user) {
    res.status(400).send("Fail -> Email is already in use!");
    return;
  }
});
```

OR

```
User.findOne({_id: {$ne: req.body.id}, "email": req.body.email})
```

Comment: thanks, I managed to solve here too :) I used ```sequelize.op.``` The excerpt I used was like this:

```id: {[Op.ne]: req.body.id}```